Different Okta Behavior With Spring Security OAuth2 Verses Auth0 Developer Edition And Entra ID
We have a developed a web application that uses spring security. Recently, we extended the options to include OAuth2. We chose an implementation approach to be vendor agnostic and does not include the vendor boot starter projects. Internally we tested against Auth0 Developer Edition and Entra ID and it worked as expected.
However when we rolled out to a client with a production version of Okta (version unknown), the authentication failed in the request for tokens. I see the following request when I call the Auth0 Developer Edition :
HTTP POST https://XXXXX/oauth/token
      Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
      Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[XXXXXXXXXXXXXX], redirect_uri=[http://xxxxxx/login/oauth2/code/okta/]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
Response 200 OK 

The same code at the client site is generating the following request:
HTTP POST https://XXXX/oauth2/XXXX/v1/token
      Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
      Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[xxxx], redirect_uri=[https://xxxx/login/oauth2/code/okta/]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED

I understand that spring classes are using the standard OAuth2 URI's to get the endpoints to invoke. I am just wondering what is causing the differences and how to resolve the issue.
adding properties
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.provider=okta
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-name=<client,name}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-id={client.id}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-secret={client.secret}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope.0=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope.1=profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope.2=email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/okta/


Did you configure client-id and client-secret in properties?

BTW: spring-security-oauth2 is end of life since 2002. You should use Spring Security 6.

@MikeRother spring-security-oauth2 is not compatible with Spring Security >4. You should remove spring-security-oauth2from your class path.

read, the text that comes when you over the spring-security-oauth2. You most probably don't have the dependencies targeted by this tag, in which case you should remove it.

I'm surprised that you don't have an Authorization=Basic xxx header with your token request. Also, my Okta token request URL is https://dev-55861937.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token (nothing between oauth2 and v1).

The current code works for both OAuth and Entra Id providers. I just turned on the logging to see the requests being sent to OAuth provider. Is there and significance to /token and /v1/token URL differences?

Probably not related to path structure (what you are using seems to be a "custom authorization server"). 401 means unauthorized (missing or invalid authorization). The main Trick I know with Okta is that authorization endpoint requires a state parameter (just like Auth0 requires an audience). But if you reach the token request, it means that the authorization was successful and an authorization-code returned. There should be a way to get more details from the failing POST response (Okta error responses are usually pretty expressive) and the root cause for this 401.

As wrote in the 1st comment, you should double / triple check the client ID and secret (values in properties and possible overrides in env variables or command-line arguments). You seem to be switching from a dev instance to a production-like one and this 401 might be due to a credentials issue.
